# How Can I show ViewDetail on another page in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 18 columns in my Database. I want to show just 5 columns on screen, and others should appear on another page When I select on Select Event.
I can Show 5 columns on screen but don't know how to show reaming data on another screen.

**I Have tried this method in "SelectedIndexChanged"***

```
GridViewRow gr = GridView1.SelectedRow;
  Response.Redirect("Show.aspx?Name=" + gr.Cells[0].Text + "&Father" + 
gr.Cells[1].Text + "&Gender" + gr.Cells[2]);
```

**and this code in Another page**

```
lblSerial.Text = Request.QueryString["Name"].ToString();
  lblName.Text = Request.QueryString["Father"].ToString();
    lblFather.Text = Request.QueryString["Gender"].ToString();
```

But by this method, I can only the data which is being shown in GridView, not the other data in the Database.

Comment: use a GridView https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I have used a gridview but I am only able to show the same data of gridview on next page. there are some other data I haven't shown on gridview, and I want them to appear on next page along with the data shown in gridview

Comment: if you been unable to do that, then quit it, start from an existing tutorial, and design your program at first from what you can do - not what you can imaging that you can do.